Coordinate format and conversion
I'm new to GIS and I have a question that I hope you'll be able to help me with.
I have a set of coordinates I obtained from a paper, that look like this:
S 00.67455, W 76.39837;
N 00.18166, W 78.93117
My first question is: What format are these coordinates in? Why are they not separated into degrees, minutes, and seconds?
I've only used coordinates that look like this before: -0.076874, -78.620597 and I was able to use them to create points in a QGIS map from a table, using the tool "Create points from table".
What do I need to do with my coordinates so I can use them in QGIS? These are for an area in Ecuador.
On that note, what is the best projection/CRS to use for Ecuador? I have points in both the northern and southern hemispheres, so I'm thinking UTM 17S is not ideal, though it's what I have used in the past.

Please keep to one question per GIS Stack Exchange Guidelines https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask - Your Coordinates are DMS https://www.latlong.net/lat-long-dms.html

Too many 6s, 7s, 8s, and 9s to be Degrees-Minutes-Seconds. Looks more DecimalDegrees, but without sign.

As Vince states, these are decimal degrees but with N, S, and W designations.  All you need to do is convert the S or W values as negative signs.
-00.67455, -76.39837 plots to Estacion Cintifica Yasuni PUNC in Equcador.

00.18166, -78.93117 also maps to Equador.

Best projections?  That would depend on the use and is an opinion based question.  Best to remove that from your question or it will be closed.
